# Is Alexa still sending the Viewport data in the Request?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I don't see the Viewport data neither from a Show or a Spot... (context.Viewport) What happened?

There used to be a section to describe the display capabilites, like this from a Spot:

```
"Viewport": {
  "currentPixelHeight": 480, 
  "currentPixelWidth": 480, 
  "dpi": 160, 
  "experiences": [
    {
      "arcMinuteHeight": 144, 
      "arcMinuteWidth": 144, 
      "canResize": false, 
      "canRotate": false
    }
  ], 
  "keyboard": [], 
  "pixelHeight": 480, 
  "pixelWidth": 480, 
  "shape": "ROUND", 
  "touch": [
    "SINGLE"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Scratch that. It magically came back. Looks like Amazon is reading Stack Overflow.

Comment: Oh good to hear, I didn't check on it recently. I figured they messed something up and didn't realize it since there was no mention about removing Viewport.

Comment: It was a hiccup!

Answer (score 1):

I have been scouring documentation for days looking for a way to get the display characteristics.  This post gave me a tiny clue, thank you very much.  I finally found out how to get them with this.  I know it seems a simple task to get the variable but I'm just beginning and the documentation isn't that friendly (or I was looking in the wrong places).  So if one prints `event['context']['Viewport']` then one can get the display characteristics when the test skill is run.

Here's my example for getting the screen width:

```
def get_display_width(event):
    try:
        width = event['context']['Viewport']['currentPixelWidth']
    except:
        width = 1
    if width < 481:
            return 1 #small hub round 480 x 480
    elif width < 962:
        return 2 #small hub 960 x 480
    elif width < 1026:
        return 3 #medium hub 1024 x 600
    else:
        return 4 #large hubs and tv's
```